# Find out if the form was submited or the page was refreshed

Tags: python, django, forms, refresh, submit

I am using a form to search for some date. The form uses GET method for date retrieval.

```
<form action="" method="GET">
  ...
  <div id="search_button"><input type="submit" value={% trans 'Search' %} name="search"></div>
</form>
```

How could I know whether the submit button was pressed or the page was refresed?

Comment: Why do you need to know the distinction?

Comment: Because my application is available for different languages.

Answer (score 0):

If someone submits the form then there'll be parameters in the query string named after your form fields. Of course, if someone then refreshes *that* page, I'm not sure that you'd be able to tell the difference between that and a form-submit.

If it's important that you can tell the difference, you should probably alter the form to use POST.

Comment: I am using the form to search for objects and using GET is the recommended way to do this.

Comment: Ok, but if your search is immutable (which I assume it is), is it really that important that you can tell the difference? In either the case where the form is submitted or where a previously-submitted-form is refreshed, I assume you'd still want to do-the-search and return-the-results anyway.

Comment: For me this difference matters. If the page is refreshed I would need another logic.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to cache the search results. If so, then you should try checking the cache instead.

Switch from '`if (form.refreshed) { use cached results }`' to '`if (cache.exists(form.GET)) { use cached results }`'

Comment: I'm not trying to cache the results. Because my application uses different languages, in some cases things get messed up. The reason is that after the user submits the form, this information remains in the url. When the language changes, the data from url remains in the same format(the format depends on the language set). My logic will handle these separate actions(refresh or submit) easier if I know what kind of action I have.

Comment: @Seitaridis, So you want to clear the query string when the language is changed? I suggest you do it with javascript.

Comment: I want to determine from Django code when a page refresh or a page submit is made, but I am afraid I can't do that.